# What is the distance from top and bottom when I set the line-height property?

Tags: html

I would like to know what is the distance between the margin and the heading. This is for PSD TO HTML pixel perfect. I have a title that has the line-height of 50px and the font size of 30px. I think the distance is 10px top and 10px bottom but I’m not sure. That’s because the font-size is 30px and the line-height is 50px so I subtract 50-30 and I divided to 2. Is the distance from top equal to 10px?
Thank you!
I attached a file so you can see what I mean and this is the html code.
[See this image with heading with line-height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVm75.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            line-height: 50px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        body {
            background: black;
        }
        #section{
            background: red;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section id="section">
<h1>Heading one</h1>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, symbol `_` has bigger space from top than `A`. But space for character usually stays the same, but it's simply not visible

Comment: Thank you! So the distance from the top is 10px and from the bottom is also 10px in this example?